# How to double split a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my string:

```
const string = "From A to the time of B : then c,
Between A and B before the time : then d,
Between A and B before the time : then e,"
```

So this is my string, now i need to convert this as follows:

```
[ {first: "From A to the time of B", second: "then c"}, {first: "Between A and B before the time", second: "then d"}, {first: "Between A and B before the time", second: "then e"} ]
```

Thus, i need first split at ":" and then at "," so i tried like this,

```
string.split(":").split(",")
```

But got error !

Please help !

Comment: so split and map and split

Comment: Well for a start Js doesn't support multi line strings with `"` so that won't work. "but got error", ok what error?

Comment: Give it a try with string template and some combination of map and split.

Answer (score 1):

Using split and map and split again

```js
const string = "From A to the time of B : then c,Between A and B before the time : then d,Between A and B before the time : then e,";

const result = string.split(",").filter(Boolean).map(function (str) {
  var parts = str.split(":");
  return { first: parts[0].trim(), second: parts[1].trim() };
});

console.log(result);
```

Other option would be to split it on either character and than loop by twos

```js
const string = "From A to the time of B : then c,Between A and B before the time : then d,Between A and B before the time : then e,";


var parts = string.split(/\s?[,:]\s?/);

var result = []
for(var i=0; i < parts.length; i+=2) {
  if (parts[i]) {
    result.push({first: parts[i], second: parts[i+1] });
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
const result = `From A to the time of B : then c,
Between A and B before the time : then d,
Between A and B before the time : then e,`.split(',').filter(Boolean).map(text => text.split(' : ')).map(text => ({ first: text[0].replace(/\n/g, ''), second: text[1] }))

console.log(result)
```